# .NET Exception Window API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a way (through some sort of API) to reuse (in my application) the following window

[image]

displayed when an exception is thrown and not caught by a .NET program?

Comment: How do you want to use it? You can always throw your own exception and not handle it.

Comment: @TomW I replaced the original text and forgot to verify the replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! I found it! It was not easy to find though :( 
Check this out [ThreadExceptionDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.threadexceptiondialog.aspx) and an [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/pages/unhandled-exceptions-windows-forms.aspx) where it is used.

Comment: @Coder Exactly! No need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: This is the same as not catching the exception! LOL

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/ExceptionDialog.aspx) describing how to create reusable exception dialog.

Comment: +1 for this excellent link. However, this does not exactly answers the question.

Comment: +1 thanks for the link. I am looking for something that comes by default in the .NET framework...